# Datatable Legacy - Update Total of Pages existed

Tags: jquery, datatable

im working with the datatables legacy to generate my dynamic table.

but in my sql i using offset rows to bring only 100 rows each time.

i try to use the pagination to get the number of the page and a dropdown to get the 
value of the rows to show on the page.

My problem is when i get my data via ajax i need to update the number of pages of the
pagination.

**For Example.**

```
Total rows 57, 
Showing rows 10, 
Total pages 6,
```

i can´t find a why to update this information.

have somone any experience with that.

**jquery code:**

```
$("#status").DataTable({
                            "bPaginate": true,
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "bLengthChange": true,
                            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20], [5, 10, 15, 20]],
                            "iDisplayLength": 5,
                            "bFilter": true,
                            "bSort": true,
                            "aaSorting": [],
                            "bInfo": true,
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "oLanguage": {
                                "sSearch": "Pesquisar:",
                                "oPaginate":
                                    {
                                        "sFirst": "<<",
                                        "sPrevious": "<",
                                        "sNext": ">",
                                        "sLast": ">>",

                                    },
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking about sending the paging parameters *to* the server, or returning the paged record counts *from* the server to the client side.

If it's the former, then you need to use [iDisplayLength](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#iDisplayLength) and [iDisplayStart](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#iDisplayStart) which are passed to the server in the request. You don't say what server-side language you're using, but you need to get these values from the querystring and use them in your SQL query, something like:

```
Request.QueryString["iDisplayStart"]
```

If you're asking about returning the paging quantities from the server, then you return the values as `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` in the json:

```
return Json(new
  {
       param.sEcho,
       iTotalRecords = rowCount,
       iTotalDisplayRecords = rowCount,
       aaData = result
  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

See [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for information about parameters passed in the datatables request and response.